# Debugging a "Metro" UI...says .exe is missing, but it was never included

Tags: wpf, debugging, visual-studio-2012, build

Hey guys im pulling my hair out....I am using Visual Studio 2013 and cannot debug the source files found at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/442856/Visual-Studio-Metro-Styles-for-WPF

Its a Modern UI application, I get the error message that ".exe cannot be found" which I understand will prevent building and debugging the solution. However. the .exe files are not even in the source folder at all!!

Is there any way to debug this, or actually create the .exe files this solution needs to build properly??? Thanks so much